# Laravel 5.2: session and token guard on the same routes

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5, authorization

We had session guard and that was enough.

Now we need to add authorization via token (in headers or GET params) and via session **on the same routes**.

Authorization via token must be stateless.

UPD: 
First, we think about create dubplicate routes.
One for session and one for token

```
// api token auth
// url: /api/test
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth:api'], 'prefix' => 'api', 'as' => 'api.'], function () {
    Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
    // 50+ routes
});

// session auth
// url: /test
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
    // 50+ routes
});
```

but it's not what we want, because urls are different.

Maybe somebody knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create new middleware AuthenticateWithToken:

```
class AuthenticateWithToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (($user = Auth::guard('api')->user())) {
            Auth::setUser($user);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Declare it in Http/Kernel.php:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'auth.api' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateWithToken::class,
    // ...
];
```

And add it before default 'auth' middleware in routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth.api', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
    // 50+ routes
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to do the same thing but using passport instead of token guard?

Comment: Nevermind just had to use 'auth.api' middleware without any others